# Stanford POS Tagger to return more then one tag

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am implementing POS tagging with the Stanford POS Tagger. However, some of the words can have multiple tags. For example word `heat`, can be noun or verb. However POS tagger return only one value for current sentence - NOUN. Is it possible to return all possible POS tags using Stanford POS Tagger. Which means that for the word `heat`, I can get NOUN and VERB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POS tagger is designed to tag a word with the proper POS tag based on the context of the sentence.