# Get all possible part-of-speech tags for a word Python

Tags: python, tags, nltk, part-of-speech

Is there any way to make this code work with a column on a data frame that contains 1 word only? I just need all POS that a single word can have. Enclosed is an example of pack which can be a NN or  VB.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

x = defaultdict(list)
for word, pos in brown.tagged_words()[1:1000000000]:
    if pos not in x[word]:      
        x[word].append(pos)    
print(x["pack"])
```

Out put: ['NN', 'VB']

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stanford POS Tagger to return more then one tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686617/stanford-pos-tagger-to-return-more-then-one-tag)

Comment: Sorry no, that will only get one POS tag per work.  The code above shows several POS tags per word. What I just need is a bit of help on working with that code to process a column on a dataframe.

Comment: I have read this NLTK POS-tagging page: 'https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html' i didn't found a function with returning more than one tag for a word. The only thing i found was that you can make several POS taggers, each of which have different N-gram size. so you can find several tags for a word according to a different neighbor of a word in a sentence or document.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51722351/get-all-possibles-pos-tags-from-a-single-word) and [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340789/get-all-possible-part-of-speech-tags-for-a-word-using-nltk) which provides a solution, i hadn't test them, but

**By Default,** Linguistic toolkits use disambiguation techniques to assign only one tag to a word (according to [this page](https://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/bnc2/bnc2guide.htm) - "section 4: DISAMBIGUATION BY WORD" and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280061/nltk-pos-tagger-is-creating-different-tags-for-the-same-word-can-anybody-explai)) bsaed on the context in which the word is used.

Also i have read [this NLTK POS-tagging](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) page, you can make several POS taggers, each of which have different N-gram size. so you can find several tags for a word according to a different neighbor of a word in a sentence or document. There are examples for context filtering in [official NLTK website](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html)

Finally, you can invite stackoverflow [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/part-of-speech/topusers) in #part-of-speach to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that I was looking for.

from lemminflect import getInflection, getAllInflections, getAllInflectionsOOV, getAllLemmas

getAllLemmas('pack')
{'NOUN': ('pack',), 'VERB': ('pack',)}

For the Dataframe, the word will be the column name of the df.

df['tag'] = df['word'].apply(lambda x: getAllLemmas(x))